# MySQL MAX() with WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know if this is possible, but I want to filter the records available for the MAX() function.

For example something like this:

`SELECT COUNT(1), MAX(age WHERE person.date_of_death IS NULL) FROM person`

I still want to count all the records, but only want to get the MAX age where date_of_death is null. Obviously I could use a subquery, but the actual query is much more complex than this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add `case` expression :

```
SELECT COUNT(1), MAX(CASE WHEN p.date_of_death IS NULL THEN age END) 
FROM person p
```